# How to use the camera on mobile device with unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a student and I want to get every single frame from the camera to do some operation. Can any one tell me how can I make it in unity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain a bit more what you mean, every single frame do an action? as in 60 frames a second? On Mobile? I would suggest [watching this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/tips/unity-tips-and-tricks-grab-bag?playlist=17114) about how to optimise memory and processor management for mobile devices. (about half way through)

Comment: What have you tried so far ? There is the `ReadPixels` function : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html to get the pixels rendered on your screen. But, *keep in mind* that doing such processing *each frame* is very "heavy".

Answer (score 1):

Well your question is quite broad as it is...

Anyway:

- If you want to do some operations every frame you can simply use [`MonoBehaviour.Update()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) which is called every frame.
- If you're looking for some Camera related operation I guess what you're looking for is called postprocessing : you can find a bit more about it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-ImageEffects.html).
- If you want to extract every frame of your game you can call [`Application.CaptureScreenshot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html) on `Update()` method : be aware that this will be extremely heavy and slow down your FPS drastically.

Hope this helps.